# how to make my php page wait for a post(xml string)?

Tags: php, xml, post

I have a Login class that will parse an xml sent from an iOS, Android phone. I'm not very good at php and my question is, how do I make my php page wait for a post? or do I just use

```
$xml = $_POST['login.xml'];
  ....
  //parse
  ....
echo $responsexml;
```

he also suggested

```
$xml=readfile("php://input");
```

to read the xml string. I'm much confused about this post business. Any help will be greatly apreaciated!

Comment: The important information here is how the client(sender) is going to send the xml datas.

Comment: @Sebas I see. Unfortunately all I know it will be a string and to some clients I have to use the second method (readfile) to get the xml

Comment: you can't answer the question without the client side code.

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry it's going to be difficult. Let see if some genius drop by..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When XML string will be sent via HTTP POST request, e. g. in your case in "login.xml" parameter, so yes, you can get this content by this code:

```
$xml = $_POST['login.xml'];
// parsing here...
```

If you do not know in which parameter data will be, you can iterate through array $_POST. But it is unusual. When you are developing an app, at first you should create API in PHP and then you have to give developers of iOS and Android apps some specification, in which format data should be transferred (or, worse, they will give you some specification of in which format they are sending data).

By the way. I think the simplest solution for this would be to send a POST request with data parameters "login" and "password", for example. PHP would than run some verification and return some session id. And for all requests of this type, it's better to avoid XML, all data can go via HTTP requests. And then you don't have to parse anything:

```
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, unfortunately it is stated in project description that XML shall be used.